# Hashing speed with true random passwords

Tags: hash, password-management, random

Just a theoretical question:

If I had ideal users, who all provide fully random 128-bit passwords,
And also, I invalidate every password shorter than 128 bits.

Then would I still need a *slow* hash function to store these passwords?

Comment: To clarify, only the [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of the password matters.  The actual length of the password is irrelevant.  That is [`correct horse battery staple` is ~44 bits of entropy](http://xkcd.com/936/) despite being 28 bytes (224-bits) long when encoded in plain ASCII.  When the entropy is significantly longer than about ~80 bits, you don't really have to worry it being brute-forcing.  (2^80 ~ 10^23; brute forcing a billion hashes per second would require 38 million computer-years to break; and every additional bit doubles the required time).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If users could be relied upon to provide truly random passwords, there would be no need to use a slow hash function.  But you can *never* rely on users for that.

Answer (score 4):

If users provided random passwords with the equivalent of 128+ bits of entropy that are never used elsewhere, there's no need for a *slow* hash function like bcrypt, scrypt, sha256crypt, sha512crypt or PBKDF.  Similarly, there would be no need for a salt on the hash.

Why?  Brute forcing is simply unfeasible when the expected time is O(2<sup>128</sup>); e.g., even with billions of computers trying billions of hashes per millisecond, you won't be able to brute force a 128-bit entropy hash in millions of years (precisely you'd have about a 1 in 10000 chance of breaking it).  Granted there's no reliable method to test the strength of user-created passwords, as entropy is highly model dependent.  E.g., a password like: `Qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm` will appear as [132 bits](http://rumkin.com/tools/password/passchk.php) despite being the order of keyboard keys and being rather low entropy.  Or if my password to security.stackexchange.com was `https://security.stackexchange.com` that calculator says 147 bits of entropy (when its extremely weak).  On the other hand, knowing the method of password generation you can reliably calculate the passwords entropy; so if you force all your users to learn a 128-bit random password you generated you can ensure their passwords are reasonably strong.

There would still be a need for a hash function though as you should never store passwords in plaintext.  An attacker should not be able to find a list of plaintext passwords in the database  from some other compromise (e.g., finding an old backup, SQL injection, memory leak, etc).  A simple hash (e.g., SHA-2) would work to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two more aspects you should take into account
1- Is your user input 'random enough'?

At the moment, bruteforcing 128 bits is unfeasible. Why use a hash function at all if the bits are random?  128 random bits will be stronger than the hashed output of the same.  Two different passwords may produce a collision in a hash function, the bigger the space to hash, the greater probability there will be collisions, while a random password would not have this issue.

2- How will someone remember 128 random bits?  Would anyone change their 128 random bit password after memorizing it?

It looks like a pain in the ass solution.